# Displaying custom posts on a specific page in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, posts

I have created custom posts and I want one page in my site to have 5 of the most recent of the custom post displayed like so:

```
<h1>Custom Posts 1</h1>
//show 5 of the most recent custom-posts-1 here

<h1>Custom Posts 2</h1>
//show 5 of the most recent custom-posts-2 here
```

How would I do this? I've looked at the wordpress post template file but I need to be able to tell my page what posts to use.  I was hoping to find for a simple function I just add to my page's editor (I have enabled it so I can add php in) but I can't find an appropriate one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend having the two groups of posts in different WordPress categories.

Then you can use [`get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts) to pull back the two different lists and print them out however you want.

```
<?php
    //A rough example
    $posts = get_posts(array( 
               'numberposts'   => 5,
               'category_name' => 'custom-posts-2',
               'orderby'       => 'post_date',
               'order'         => 'DESC'
             ));
?>
```

Comment: Ok, well the custom posts are basically items people want to give away or ask for.  Part of the custom posts is a custom field asking the user to choose the category his item comes under e.g. furniture or white goods.  Therefore the posts will already have a category here.  Is it possible to assign a top level category to my custom posts then e.g. 'wanted' category and a 'offered'.  This would need to be assigned in my function that creates the custom posts though, and I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: It depends a bit on how you're handling the custom fields. The brute force approach would be to get all posts in the top level category containing both the "wanted" and "offered" posts. Then loop over them to split them into the two subgroups.

Comment: I'd rather assign the category to them in my code.  But looking at the wordpress doc for register_post_type there is no way to assign a category, there is a parameter to assign a taxonomy though.  I might try that.

Comment: you were partially right.  I found out that the get_posts function takes a post type parameter, so I could simply pass it the name of my post type

Comment: Excellent! Glad it's sorted out.